# Insert Angular Form Data in MongDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, forms, crud

I have created a feedback form with angular and now i want to insert the data from the form into mongodb database(bookstore) in collection(feedback). I am inserting data in mongodb atlas and made the connection. I dont know what to do next.

```
contactus.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contactus',
  templateUrl: './contactus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contactus.component.css']
})
export class ContactusComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form.value)         // FORM DATA VALUE 
  
    //..............

    //INSERT THE FORM DATA IN MONGO DB 
  }

}
```

```
feedback.js

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "......";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
    if(!err){
        console.log('MongoDB connected...')
    } else
    {
        console.log('Error in DB connection: ' + err );
    }
});
```

Comment: I hope that is not your actual atlas connection string.. besides that, what is feedback.js? A node script? Because you really want to do db inserts serverside, not in the browser..

Comment: No i changed the password . But how do i insert the data in mongo after i got the form data in object form. What steps do i follow?